# Read a text file into an array in plain C

Tags: c, file, gcc, io, stdio

Is there a way to read a text file into a one dimensional array in plain C? Here's what I tried (I am writing hangman):

```
int main() {
    printf("Welcome to hangman!");

    char buffer[81];
    FILE *dictionary;
    int random_num;
    int i;
    char word_array[80368];

    srand ( time(NULL) );

    random_num = rand() % 80368 + 1;
    dictionary = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(buffer, 80, dictionary) != NULL){
        printf(buffer); //just to make sure the code worked;
        for (i = 1; i < 80368; i++) {
            word_array[i] = *buffer;
        }
    }

    printf("%s, \n", word_array[random_num]);
    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Word_array chould be an array of char *, not char. Buffer needs to be dynamically allocated (your single buffer is overwritten each fgets, and the word_array assignments will all be the same.  You should look up some sample C text handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing a couple of things;

First; you're storing a single char. `word_array[i] = *buffer;` means to copy a single character (the first one on the line/in the buffer) into each (and every) single-char slot in word_array.

Secondly, your array will hold 80K characters, not 80K words. Assuming that that's the length of your dictionary file, you can't fit it all in there using that loop.

> I'm assuming you have 80,368 words in your dictionary file. That's about 400,000 words less than `/usr/share/dict/words` on my workstation, though, but sounds like a reasonable size for hangman…

If you want a one-dimensional array intentionally, for some reason, you'll have to do one of three things:

- pretend you're on a mainframe, and use 80 chars for every word:

  ```
    char word_array[80368 * 80];

  memcpy (&(word_array[80 * i]), buffer, 80);
  ```
- create a parallel array with indices to the start of each line in a huge buffer

  ```
     int last_char = 0;
     char* word_start[80368];
     char word_array[80368 * 80];
     for ( … i++ ) {
         memcpy (&word_array[last_char], buffer, strlen(buffer));
         word_start[i] = last_char;
         last_char += strlen(buffer);
     }
  ```
- switch to using an array of pointers to char, one word per slot.

  ```
    char* word_array[80368];

    for (int i = 0; i < 80368, i++) {
         fgets (buffer, 80, dictionary);
         word_array[i] = strdup (buffer);
    }
  ```

I'd recommend the latter, as otherwise you have to guess at the max size or waste a lot of RAM while reading. (If your average word length is around 4-5 chars, as in English, you're on average wasting 75 bytes per word.)

I'd also recommend dynamically allocating the word_array:

```
   int max_word = 80368;
   char** word_array = malloc (max_word * sizeof (char*));
```

… which can lead you to a safer read, if your dictionary size ever were to change:

```
   int i = 0;
   while (1) {
        /* If we've exceeded the preset word list size, increase it. */
        if ( i > max_word ) {
            max_word *= 1.2; /* tunable arbitrary value */
            word_array = realloc (word_array, max_word * sizeof(char*));
        }
        /* Try to read a line, and… */
        char* e = fgets (buffer, 80, dictionary);
        if (NULL == e) { /* end of file */
            /* free any unused space */
            word_array = realloc (word_array, i * sizeof(char*));
            /* exit the otherwise-infinite loop */
            break;
        } else {
            /* remove any \r and/or \n end-of-line chars */
            for (char *s = &(buffer[0]); s < &(buffer[80]); ++s) {
               if ('\r' == *s || '\n' == *s || '\0' == *s) {
                  *s = '\0'; break;
               }
            }
            /* store a copy of the word, only, and increment the counter.
             * Note that `strdup` will only copy up to the end-of-string \0,
             * so you will only allocate enough memory for actual word
             * lengths, terminal \0's, and the array of pointers itself. */
            *(word_array + i++) = strdup (buffer);
        }
    }
    /* when we reach here, word_array is guaranteed to be the right size */
    random = rand () % max_word;
    printf ("random word #%d: %s\n", random, *(word_array + random));
```

Sorry, this is posted in an hurry, so I haven't tested the above. Caveat emptor.

Answer (score 3):

This part is wrong:

```
while (fgets(buffer, 80, dictionary) != NULL){
    printf(buffer); //just to make sure the code worked;
    for (i = 1; i < 80368; i++) {
        word_array[i] = *buffer;
    }
}
```

You are copying 80368 chars from `buffer` which has size 81.  Change it to:

```
i = 0;
while (fgets(buffer, 80, dictionary) != NULL){
    printf(buffer); //just to make sure the code worked;
    for (j = 0; j < 80; j++) {
        word_array[i++] = buffer[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi, you missed a semicolon in line 1 ;-)

Comment: @AhmadGaffoor nothing useful, I just didn't remember if fgets was guaranteed to 0-terminated and felt paranoid.

Comment: printf("%s, \n", word_array[random_num]);

Comment: That line does not print the corresponding array value. it prints out (null).  What did I do wrong? Is it the identifier?

Comment: `word_array[random_num]` is a `char`, while the `"%s"` format specifier requires a `char*`.  If you wanted an array of words you should declare `word_array` as `char word_array[80][80386]`, or something similar.

Comment: … this is going to copy 80 chars (needed or not) from `buffer` into a sequential part of `word_array` … but then his random-selection code will choose a character offset to jump into the array …

Comment: actually, the random selection code is mine. But he rewrote while and for loops